# How to create a ReactiveUI Grid in UWP?

Tags: uwp

[image]

I want to make a Grid like this.The columns in every row is just 7,not more than 7 and not less than 7.
And I want to make it be a ReactiveUI.That is whenever the window larger,all the 
 items in grid turn to be larger.Whenever the window smaller,all the 
 items in grid turn to be smaller.
So I wrote the code like this:

```
 <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Name="FileItemsControl" Margin="30">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="10" Orientation="Horizontal">

                    </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Red" Margin="10,0" MaxHeight="130">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Viewbox Margin="10">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE8A5;" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <Viewbox Grid.Row="2">
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding FileName}"></TextBlock>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

It turn out to be some problems like this:
1.As you see,one row has 7 columns ,but not full of the grid.What I need is to divide the grid into 7 parts in every row.

[image]

2.Whenever I make the window smaller,the columns in every row is not 7 any more.
[image]

3.Even I used the viewbox,whenever I make the window smaller or larger,all the size of items in grid won't change.I think it is realte to the problem 1,but I am not sure.

Maybe I have not explain it clearly and I apologize for my poor English.But I hope if you can help me about this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Google "UniformGrid".

Comment: @JustinXL I have used UniformGrid in WPF.But there is no UniformGrid in UWP any more.Need I use custom control make a new one?

Comment: There are many implementations on GitHub. Did you google?

Comment: @JustinXL Yeah,I see.Let me try this.

Comment: For my poor knowledge,I don't clearly understand the code clearly.I trid it and it works.But the only problem is when I set 4 row/4 colunm and added 18 items,the verticalscrollbar do not show,some items was be hideen.I don't know how to solve this.@JustinXL

Comment: Try wrapping it within a ScrollViewer.

Comment: @JustinXL I tried yet,the verticalscrollbar showed in ScrollViewer,but the verticalscrollbar didn't expand and can't scroll.I doubt if it is bug of the UniformGrid.

Comment: Put your project in GitHub n I will have a look.

Comment: @JustinXL I am sorry about away from computer for a long time.Here is my GitHub code:https://github.com/kyuranger/UniformGridForUWP. I was cloned and  edited from this :https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152895/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-melon-ng).